# Bash-shell script revise and suggestion

Tags: bash, shell, loops, automation

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to automatise a process.
I think the structure is ok, but i get notice which i think that it should not be there

```
# STEP 1#
echo " Untar the file s"
time tar -xf $tarfiles
time tar -xf *.tar

#STEP 2#
fname=(wnd10m.gdas.2010*.grb2)
echo " convert into .nc "
cdo -f nc copy $fname $fname.nc

#STEP 3#
ofile1=$fname.nc
echo "re-format into structured grid 0.5x0.5"
cdo remapbil,r720x361 $ofile1 remap$R.nc

#STEP 4#
ofile2=$remapR.nc
echo "produce desired mesh"
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 $ofile2 $grid.nc

#STEP 5#
ofile3=$grid.nc
echo "merge the files based on tstep"
cdo mergetime $ofile3 final$R.nc
```

STEP 1 and STEP 2 are performed although it only manipulates and alters one of the file that it was included in the .tar file.

The process so far gives out the STEP 1 & 2, but during STEP 3 I do not get the new file as `remap$R.nc` with R being an additional ending so generated is not confused with other produced in the previous step.

After I run it this is what i get

```
convert into .nc 

cdo copy: Processed 987365376 values from 2 variables over 744 timesteps ( 234.66s )
re-format into structured grid 0.5x0.5

cdo remapbil: Processed 987365376 values from 2 variables over 744 timesteps ( 53.59s )
produce desired mesh

Error (cdo sellonlatbox) : Output file name .nc is equal to input file name on position 1!

merge the files based on tstep

cdo mergetime: Open failed on >.nc<
No such file or directory
```

I am trying to de-bug my file but don't know what I have done wrong, because the process is supposed to handle a lot of files converting them into every stage I paid significant attention to assigning correct and different `fnames`.

I would be grateful if you could have a look and give me your inputs.

p.s. cdo is a code I am using so you can disregard it, my focus is on the process itself

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare these:

```
cdo remapbil,r720x361 $ofile1 remap$R.nc
```

and

```
ofile2=$remapR.nc
```

this looks like a classical typo

Comment: @Bushmils. I did in that form so as to add a different ending to every file in convert, and then be used as the input file for the next set of commands
Although i think i messed up in that portion, i will change it and re-run.

Comment: did change that but the outcome was


cdo sellonlatbox: Open failed on >.nc<
No such file or directory
merge the files based on tstep

cdo mergetime: Open failed on >.nc<
No such file or directory

Comment: "did in that form so as to add a different ending to every file" i don't understand. Nowhere do you assign anything to variable R, therefore its contents are undefined, or you didn't show what you assigned.

Comment: no i have not assign anything to R, I just wanted R to be the ending of the normal fname based on the previous ifile used.
So the output from that option would have the name of the (ifile+R).nc.
I thought i didn't had to assign it.. my mistake, i ll do try to alter it and assign R=1 at the start of the script

Comment: "ofile2=$remapR.nc"   with variable remapR empty results in ofile2 having the value ".nc", which is your problem.  What you may be looking for is the form    value="${variable}string", or  "ofile2=${remap}R.nc"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56697/discussion-between-george-and-bushmills).

Answer (score 2):

`$remapR` is different to `remap$R`. Move your dollar sign.

You can use `set -xv` to debug your script.

Comment: Is the command used prior to every set of commands or at the start of the scipt?

Answer (score 0):

Hello all  as a continuation to the issue i had and the user @Bushmills help me a lot (thanks!!!)

I attach the code that I did with advice i got, i tested and it works, so hopefully another user (novice like me) may find this useful.

```
file="wnd10m.gdas."
year='2010'
month='01 02'
ext="grb2"

for((y=$year;y<=$year;y++));
do
    for m in $month
    do
    fname=$file$y$m.$ext

    #STEP 1#
    cdo -f nc copy $fname $fname.nc

    #STEP 2#
    ofile1=$fname.nc

    cdo remapbil,r720x361 $ofile1 R$ofile1 #produces a file with the name of the R+ofile1
```

example if the previous file was named FILE the command will produce a new file named RFILE
        #STEP 3#
        ofile2=($R*.nc)
use all the file starting with R

```
    cdo sellonlatbox,$lon1,$lon2,$lat1,$lat2 $ofile2 grid_$ofile2

    done
done
```

thank you for the help

Comment: glad it worked for you. but ... "ofile2=($R*.nc)" - you're sure about that?  (variable R still not defined anywhere)

Comment: @Bushmills Yes it worked and i posted it, perhaps someone with similar problem may be helped by that, I edited the code above to show what the R is. Hope its clearer

Comment: now i am just left with a final step that is a bit tricky , but hopefully this code will be helpful in the community

Comment: "($R*.nc) use all the file starting with R" is not what that is doing, Just try:   ls $R*   - according your logic, only files starting with R should show ...

Comment: @Bushmills yes it does